# about representations of a simple $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

We know that every simple $C^*$-algebra is primitive, say it has a faithful non-zero irreducible representation. The converse is not necessarily true. An counterexample is just the $B(H)$ when $H$ is of infinite dimension.

But if  every irreducible representation of $C^*$-algebra $A$ is faithful, whether $A$ is simple?

Thank you for all helps!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. What you do is show that if $A$ is not simple, then there is a non-faithful irrep.

If $J\subset A$ is a non-trivial ideal, then consider an irreducible representation of $A/J$ into $B(H_J)$; then $A\to A/J\to B(H_J)$ is an irreducible representation of $A$ with kernel that at least contains $J$, so it is not faithful.

Comment: Oh, that's right. It is easier than I expected. I tried to consider some thing about a restriction irreducible representation on $J$ w.r.t some pure state. Anyway, thanks.